# "Could be" vs. "could be entering"

Tags: modal-verbs, present-tense, present-continuous

> France **could be entering** a new age of deep political instability.
>
> Thousands of jihadists **could be entering** Tunisia, and this would be the greatest force of instability in the North African country.

Can we just say "could enter" instead of "could be entering"? What is the difference?

Comment: No, I think  I have to change "be enter" to "enter" as  "could be enter" seems gramatically wrong.

Comment: Entering is a present participle. We us present participles to express the idea of something that is happening continuously. In this context, the use of an infinitive would suggest that thousands of jihadists might rock up all at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much Java. Good point for me and very helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't say "could be enter".  It doesn't mean something different, it's just wrong.  This is because the sentences are referring to the [*present continuous*](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/present-tense/present-continuous) tense, which is made with the verb "to be" and the *present participle* of the verb:

- France *is entering* a new age
- jihadists *are entering* Tunisia
- she *was eating* spaghetti
- they *were sleeping*
  etc.

What might make the original sentences more confusing are the use of [the modal *could*](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modals-can-could-able.htm).  When you use *could*, the verb following it is in the bare infinitive, but if you're using the present continuous, the participle stays a participle.  So it works like this:

- present tense: She **eats** spaghetti.
- present continuous: She **is eating** spaghetti.
- modal *could* and present tense: She **could eat** spaghetti.
- present continuous with modal *could*: She **could be eating** spaghetti.

Comment: Thank you a lot, so "jahadists could be entring" is in the present continous AND it indicates that "entring" will be continous not that jahadists will rock up all at the same time as Javatte mention .. right?

Comment: @GamalThomas - Correct, it's the present continuous, and it indicates that they're in the process of doing it.